# Vue Hooper mutate property

Tags: vuejs2

Does someone have any idea to lock/unlock vue hooper’s drag property after initialization?
It seems no method to modify the property, and if I mutate the property directly, it will throw out an error on it

---

https://baianat.github.io/hooper/api.html#methods

Comment: What exactly is your end goal? What does your current code look like? What exactly do you mean by "lock" and "unlock"? Looking at the API docs I see no method or property named `drag`. You need to be more specific and include more details in your question.

Comment: @chipit24
thanks for replied
I finally used customized event listener to override hooper's drag properties
so that I can enable and disable drag functions
.addEventListener("touchstart", this.hooperRef.onDragStart, { passive: true });